# semicolon single expression in a for loop

Tags: syntax, ocaml

Why is there a semicolon at the end of `Proc.num_stack_slots.(i) <- 0` in the following code?
I thought semicolons are separators in OCaml. Can we always put an optional semicolon for the last expression of a block?

```
for i = 0 to Proc.num_register_classes - 1 do
  Proc.num_stack_slots.(i) <- 0;
done;
```

See https://github.com/def-lkb/ocaml-tyr/blob/master/asmcomp/coloring.ml line 273 for the complete example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need for a semicolon after this expression, but as a syntactic courtesy, it is allowed here. In the example, you referenced, there is a semicolon, because after it a second expression follows.

Essentially, you can view a semicolon as a binary operator, that takes two-unit expressions, executes them from left to right, and returns a unit.

```
val (;): unit -> unit -> unit
```

then the following example will be more understandable:

```
for i = 1 to 5 do
    printf "Hello, ";
    printf "world\n"
done
```

here `;` works just a glue. It is allowed to put a `;` after the second expression, but only as the syntactic sugar, nothing more than a courtesy from compiler developers.

If you open a parser definition of the OCaml compiler you will see, that an expression inside a `seq_expr` can be ended by a semicolumn:

```
seq_expr:
  | expr        %prec below_SEMI  { $1 }
  | expr SEMI                     { reloc_exp $1 }
  | expr SEMI seq_expr            { mkexp(Pexp_sequence($1, $3)) }
```

That means that you can even write such strange code:

```
let x = 2 in x; let y = 3 in y; 25
```

Comment: Your last example does not compile without warning though (Warning 10: this expression should have type unit). Each expression in a sequence (except for the last) is expected to be of type unit.

Comment: it compiles, it is only warning, that says, that you're doing something wrong. And compiler is true about this. Because semantically it is a nonsense. I'm just demonstrating to you syntax capabilities. With semicolumn, syntactically, you can separate any expressions, but if they do not have a unit type, then you will get a warning.

Comment: Yes I know. I just thought it was worth mentioning in your answer.