# OCaml: pell function with int lists

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

I am trying to write a simple function in OCaml

```
let rec pell (i: int) =
(if i <= 2 then i (*if given n is less tahn 2 then return 2, else return previous n-1 th term and n-2 nd term recursively*)
  else if i>2 then
  2 * pell i - 1 + pell i - 2

else failwith "unimplemented" (*else fail with unimplemented message*)
);;
```

Write an infinite precision version of the pell function from before

```
pell2 0 = []

pell2 1 = [1]

pell2 7 = [9; 6; 1]

pell2 50 = [2; 2; 5; 3; 5; 1; 4; 2; 9; 2; 4; 6; 2; 5; 7; 6; 6; 8; 4]
```

I have written below code for this:

```
let rec pell2 i =

(if i <= 2 then
  [] -> i;
  else if i=0 then [];
  else if i>2 then                                (*finding pell number and using sum function to 
output list with infinite precision...*)
  [] -> pell2 i-1 + pell2 i-2;

else failwith "unimplemented"

);;
```

but still has some syntax errors. Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: What is this `->`? Where does `n` come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
if i <= 2 then
     [] -> i
```

In snippets like this, the `->` is invalid. It looks like you might be mixing pattern matching with `match ... with ...` and if/else up.

Also, you're first checking if `i` is less than or equal to 2, but then you have an `else` to test for `i` being equal to zero. The first check means the second is never going to happen.

Comment: Oh yes. blunder I would correct it. I simply want to add values in list in 1st and last line.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's look at the examples for the output of `pell2`. We see that `pell2` has a single integer parameter, and returns a list of integers. So, we know that the function we want to create has the following type signature:

```
pell2: int -> int list
```

Fixing (some but not all of) the syntax errors and trying to maintain your logic,

```
let rec pell2 i =
  if i=0 then []
  else if i <= 2 then i
  else if i>2 then pell2 i-1 + pell2 i-2
```

Note that I removed the semicolons at the end of each expression since OCaml's use of a semicolon in its syntax is specifically for dealing with expressions that evaluate to unit `()`. See ivg's excellent [explanation on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286734/ocaml-semicolon-single-expression-in-a-for-loop). The major flaw with this code is that it does not type check. We see that we conditionally return a list, and otherwise return an `int`. Notice how above we defined that pell2 should return an `int list`. So, we can begin fixing this by wrapping our `int` results in a list:

```
let rec pell2 n = 
  if n = 0 then []
  else if n <= 2 then [n]
  else ... something that will return the Pell number as a list ...
```

As you have already written, the `else` branch can be written using recursive calls to the pell2 function. However, we can't write it as you did previously, because pell2 evaluates to a list, and the binary operator `+` only works on two integers. So, we will have to define our own way of summing lists. Calling this `sum_lists`, we are left with the following code:
We can now fully define our function pell2:

```
let rec pell2 n =
  if n = 0 then []
  else if n <= 2 then [n]
  else (* Pell(n) = (2 * Pell(n-1)) + Pell(n-2) *)
    let half_of_first_term = pell2 n-1 in
    let first_term = sum_lists half_of_first_term half_of_first_term in
    let second_term = pell2 n-2 in
    sum_lists first_term second_term
```

So, all that is left is to define sum_lists, so that we are properly summing together two lists of the same format as the return type of pell2. The signature for sum_lists would be

```
sum_lists: int list -> int list -> int list
```

I'll give a basic outline of the implementation, but will leave the rest for you to figure out, as this is the main crux of the assignment problem.

```
let sum_lists lst1 lst2 =
  let rec sum_lists_helper lst1 lst2 carry =  
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], [] -> if carry = 1 then [1] else []
    | h::t, []
    | [], h::t -> ...
    | h1::t1, h2::t2 -> ...
  in
  sum_lists_helper lst1 lst2 0
```